# Strange @font-face issue in IE11 (renders only after you inspect an element in developer tools)

Tags: css, font-face, internet-explorer-11

I have some web fonts that work correctly in all browsers except IE11. The strange thing is, if you go to this page: http://cscart.create26.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=179 and then inspect the "features" bullet points with IE11 developer tools, suddenly all the fonts work. Any ideas?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black';
    src: url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.svg#helvetica-condensed-black-sRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Condensed-Black';
    src: url('../media/fonts/helvetica-condensed-black-webfont.svg#helvetica-condensed-black-sRg') format('svg');
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting bug, can you please post an isolated case or jsfiddle or similar site ?

Comment: looks like I can't duplicate it on jsfiddle, unfortunately. The even weirder thing is that some of the elements on the page in the font render correctly, but others don't... For example, the "Learn More: Fire Building" button should be the same font as the "Add to Cart" button, and they are in Chrome and FF, but not in IE _unless_ you inspect the element in developer tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had a blank font-family declaration on the body tag. I must have forgotten to remove it when I was making some changes. Removing the blank "font-family: ;" fixed the issue.

Comment: On my case, I had a `font` with one extra `"` that wasn't doing anything. Looks like this happens when there's something wrong with a CSS parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here. But if you check your developer tool's network tab, you'll see you're loading a lot of variations of the same font. In Chrome, you're loading both the WOFF and the SVG version of Helvetica Black Condensed, and the SVG, WOFF *and* TTF for Helvetica Condensed.

I figure improving your `@font-face` rule will reduce the chance of weird browser quirks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unrelated to the question but may help someone stumbling upon this post.

IE11 not printing web page.  It turns out that CSS files that reference @font-face in them will result in IE11 printing to fail.

Tested and confirmed on Windows 7 Professional.