# Fonts in Internet Explorer only load after I inspect the element

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face, internet-explorer-11

I am using a custom font with my site (proximanova). In using @font-face, it's working fine with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc., but not in internet explorer. It seems to be loading Times New Roman instead. Oddly though, when I use the developer tools to explore it, it changes to the correct font. See this gif here (in this example it changes from Times New Roman to ProximaNova Bold as soon as I inspect the elements): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZVej.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this, I came across this thread ([Strange @font-face issue in IE11 (renders only after you inspect an element in developer tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748573/strange-font-face-issue-in-ie11-renders-only-after-you-inspect-an-element-in-d)) which, of course, I didn't come across before. Sure enough, I had empty font-family property and, in internet explorer, it apparently won't fall back to the inherited font.